# problems searching database to match user input

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to search the database and see if it matches the users entry. However with my code so far I just keep getting "Student doesn't exist" when I enter a students name and number that is in the database and when I enter in a name and number that doesn't exist it displays nothing. I am new to PHP and mysql it would be really appreciated if someone can help me out and explain why my code isn't working. My form is on a separate page. Here is where I am asking the users to enter in their name just to show that I'm pulling in the right $_POST. I am only testing echoing out the name and number to make sure that the code is working... which at this point it is now.

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">


              Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" maxlength="50">
              <br><br>

              Student Number: <input type="text" name= "snumber" required="required" maxlength="9">
              <br><br>
```

next.php

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

//linking up to the database
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die (mysqli_connect_error());

//making a variable from the user data
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST["name"]);
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST["snumber"]);
$course = $_POST["pcourse"];

// select all from table student which show student name and number

$squery = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE uid='$number' AND student = '$name'";
$sresult = mysqli_query($link, $squery);

// check is name and number entered by user equals what is in database
$sfound =0;
while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($sresult)) {

  if ($name == $srow['uid'] && $number == $srow['student']) {

    echo "$srow[uid] $srow[student]";

  } else{
    echo "Student doesn't exist";

    $sfound =1;
  }  // end of if ($name == $srow['uid'] && $number == $srow['student'])
} // end of while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($sresult))

mysqli_close ($link);
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <br>
    <input type = "submit" value="back" name="back">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the comparison is backwards inside the loop?  .... comparing `$name` to the `uid`, and `$number` to the `student`??

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` seems Ok although the example is missing a closing `</form>` tag.

Now to the `PHP`. I fixed some errors. Here is the code:

PHP

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

//linking up to the database
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die (mysqli_connect_error());

//making a variable from the user data
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST["name"]);
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST["snumber"]);
$course = $_POST["pcourse"];

// select all from table student which show student name and number

$squery = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE uid=".$number." AND student = '".$name."'";
$sresult = mysqli_query($link, $squery);

// check if name and number entered by user equals what is in database
$sfound =0;
while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sresult))
{
    if ($name == $srow['student'] && $number == $srow['uid']) echo $srow['uid'].' '.$srow[student];
    else 
    {
        echo "Student doesn't exist";
        $sfound =1;
    } // end of if ($name == $srow['student'] && $number == $srow['uid'])
} // end of while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($sresult))

mysqli_close ($link);
?>
```

Comment: Know that `mysqli_fetch_array` defaults to [MYSQLI_BOTH](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), so the results can be used by row index and/or column name.

Comment: You are right. I need to erase that line. Thanks, upvoting for helpful.

Comment: Yes, the aspect as to what you said earlier about "the same field names" is true, and is referenced in that link, though some might overlook that point.

Comment: I agree. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Paul T for catching my mistake in the comparison, I can't believe I missed that. Also thank you to Ivan86 for helping me get the names to print out. You guys have been a great help

Comment: Oh, wow, nice catch, didn't see the comparison problem. I edited my answer to be correct. No problem @bldb, if an answer solved your problem mark it as accepted please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need check out the results produced from `mysqli_real_escape_string` they are probably null. That is possibly the reason why your database queries retrieves 0 rows. If your connection `$link` is empty too, this should be the reason in first place.